# Accidentally moved file to `,` (comma)

Tags: linux, command-line, files, filesystems

I logged in as a root user and when moving a file, instead of:

```
mv myfile .
```

I entered

```
mv myfile ,
```

And now my file is gone but I am not sure where to. Where has it moved to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You renamed the file to ","

To undo that

```
mv , myfile
```

Comment: Oh my!...Been staring at the screen for too long. Missed the `,` at the top of the `ls` output! Thanks Thomas!